# Melting Points of Animal Fats and Body Temperature

Tags: lipids

Melting points of animal fats used in cooking vary quite significantly. In some cases being above the body temperature of the animal, and in other cases being well below (cf the examples below).

- Lard: melts 30-48°C depending on where in the pig it's taken from. Back fat mostly melts below the pig's body temperature (39–40°C), whilst leaf fat mostly melts above it.
- Goose fat: melts 25-37°C, so quite cool, and whilst I wasn't able to find a number for adult goose body temperature, I found the numbers 39–42°C for goslings online, meaning all the goose fat would be expected to be liquid.
- Beef tallow: melts around 45–50°C, so well above a cow's body temperature of 38-39°C, meaning all the fat would be expected to be solid.

Obviously the fats here are in the form they're used for cooking, after they've been rendered out of whatever structure they're stored in in the living animal (presumably within cells and not in bulk), but does the fact that some of these fats will be solid, and others liquid, at their animal's usual body temperatures have any effect on how the body stores, moves, and uses the fats?

Comment: From your question, I would expect that really well-marbled beef cattle would have some difficulty with some movements (though I admit to having little knowledge of where every cut of beef comes from on the body.) Do you believe that animals walk around with solid fat? I have difficulty imagining that, but I could be wrong. Solid fat would seem so... restrictive.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I'm assuming that the fats are not stored in bulk but within cells, which could allow for the necessary flexibility. Having solid fats stored in bulk definitely does seem like it would cause problems

Comment: you basically want a book on lipids in the body, lipids are used for all kinds of things in the body and in many states.